# How to map items from an object that are unique and not repeating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, conditional-rendering

I am making an E-Commerce react native app and in the CART section of the app, I want every item added in a cart with the same ID (categoryID as you can see in the console) to render only once, but in my case if I add 3 items with same id in the cart, I will see 3 different listItems of their respected items. I want my map function to show 1 list item if there are multiple items with same id with quantity getting added. My code so far is just rendering every selected product as a separate item:

```
renderItems() {
let items = [];
this.state.cartItems.map((item, i) => {
  console.log(item)
  items.push(
    <ListItem
      key={i}
      last={this.state.cartItems.length === i + 1}
      onPress={() => this.itemClicked(item)}
    >
      <Thumbnail square style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }} source={{ uri: item.productdetail.image }} />
      <Body style={{ paddingLeft: 10 }}>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 16 }}>

          {item.productdetail.name}

        </Text>

        <Text style={{ fontSize: 14, fontStyle: 'italic' }}>Price: {item.productdetail.price}</Text>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 14, fontStyle: 'italic' }}>Quantity: {item.quantity > 1 ? item.quantity : 1}</Text>

      </Body>
      <Right>
        <Button style={{ marginLeft: -25 }} transparent onPress={() => this.removeItemPressed(item)}>
          <Icon size={30} style={{ fontSize: 30, color: '#95a5a6' }} name='ios-remove-circle-outline' />
        </Button>
      </Right>
    </ListItem>
  );
});
return items;}
```

The result of console.log is as follows
[image]

This is how my cart looks like
[image]

Now as you can see the cart should display only one listItem with same product have quantity=18

Comment: filter the data based on its `id` then iterate through content using `map`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering you have a simple data set like this :

```
const rawItemsData = [
    {id: 1, qty: 2},
    {id: 1, qty: 3},
    {id: 2, qty: 1},
    {id: 1, qty: 2},
    {id: 2, qty: 5},
    {id: 3, qty: 6}
];
```

If you want to get an array with unique item ids and summed qty, you can use reduce :

```
const uniqueItemsData = rawItemsData.reduce((prev, item) => {
    const existingItem = prev.find(({id}) => id === item.id);
    if(existingItem)
        existingItem.qty = existingItem.qty + item.qty;
    else
        prev.push(item);
   return prev;
 }, []); //-> [ { id: 1, qty: 7 }, { id: 2, qty: 6 }, { id: 3, qty: 6 } ];


 //Then you can use your code : 
 uniqueItemsData.map((item, id) => {
     //..
 });
```

Comment: In prev.find(({id}) => id === item.id);, what will I get in the 'id'?

Comment: This line is using object destructuring. `find` will loop through the existing items and execute a callback. In this callback, the variable `id` will hold the value of the current item `id` property

Comment: put it simply, you could also write : `prev.find((testItem) => testItem.id === item.id);`

Comment: You edited my answer, which made it less readable so I rejected the edit. But yes, I think you had it right

Comment: I am having a type error: '' undefined is not an object (testItem.productDetail)"

Comment: Can you suggest me that line according my data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177794/discussion-between-logar-and-abbu-jan).

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you have to make a simple control before pushing, whether the item exists or not. It's up to you to design it:

For example, you could create another list that holds the unique items. In such a page, I believe it is useful to hold the unique items, you might need related information somewhere else too. And this list shouldn't require setState because it's just for the control.

```
this.state.uniqueItems = [];
```

In each push, add the item to the uniqueItems. Do not use setState here because it will cause redundant render:

```
this.state.uniqueItems.push(item);
```

In the map function, before pushing, check if it the id exists in the unique list. You could use a simple for loop, or lodash library, or Array's find method here.